# Как исправить ошибку "Can't resolve symbol" в запросе HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Помогите исправить ошибку в следующем методе:

```
public List<Item> getAll() {
    return DBService.getSessionFactory()
        .getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery("from Item", Item.class)
        .list();
}
```

Код компилируется нормально, но статический анализатор подчёркивает в выражении `"from Item"` слово `Item` и пишет `Can't resolve symbol 'Item'`. Используется Intellij IDEA. Если в `Project Structure -> Facets` добавить JPA, то это предупреждение исчезает. Зато появляется другое предупреждение в классах, аннотированных `@Entity`, например:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
...
}
```

Здесь в строке `@Table(name = "items")` анализатор подчёркивает слово `items` и появляется предупреждение `Cannot resolve table 'items'`.
Аналогично со строкой `@Column(name = "ID")`.Здесь подчёркивается слово `"ID"`.
При этом компиляция происходит успешно и приложение нормально работает.
Что нужно сделать, чтобы убрать предупреждения анализатора?

Comment: если не ошибаюсь. когда нет подключения к базе через tools, то выдает такую ошибку. можно это выключить в инспекций. наводите на ошибку и всплывает желтый значок, клик -> отключить эту проверку

Comment: В правом нижнем углу висит жучок, кликни на него и появится окно, в котором можно убрать инспекцию.

Comment: @Senior спасибо, сделал через подключение к БД

Comment: @Roman инспекцию убрать дело не хитрое, как-бы не проморгать потом баг из-за отключенной инспекции

Comment: Тогда Измени вопрос чтобы было понятно о чем там написано

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда отсуствует подключение к базе в Tool Windows -> Database, то будет выдавать эту ошибку.

Можно либо держать коннекшн, либо отключить инспекцию. Для этого поставьте курсос на ошибку, появится желтая лампа -> клик -> Disable inspection