# Hibernate. Intellij Idea ругается на несуществующие названия столбцов таблицы

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

Хочу, чтобы создаваемые классы-модели или поля имели определенное имя в БД. Но при указании, например

```
@Column(name = "name")
private String userName;
```

идея жалуется на несуществующее поле name.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно его и нет в БД, но я рассчитывал, что оно должно создаться само (тем более, если явно не задавать имя, все прекрасно работает).

hibernate.cfg.xml содержит `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`.

Единственное решение, которое я нашел, так это выбрать "Assign Data Sources" в настройках Properties (собственно, Intellij и сама предлагает это сделать), но это не помогает.

Все же хочу отметить, что код работает и без того, просто любопытства ради интересуюсь.

Comment: Можете логи к вопросу добавить?

Comment: похоже на дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/952518/209435

Comment: Если поля нет в бд, то подключение датасурсов не поможет